# O que faz o git stash create?

Tags: git

Sempre uso o `git stash`, que acaba fazendo um `git stash push`, e manda para uma pilha, e recupero as alterações depois usando o `git stash pop`.
Até ai tudo bem, mas descobri que existe o comando `git stash create` que deve criar um save do meu trabalho.

Acontece que testei o comando, que retorna um valor parecido com um hash, mas não adiciona nada na pilha, que dá pra confirmar com o `git stash list`, então a minha pergunta é, para que serve o `git stash create`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou explicar utilizando como base a documentação do `git stash create`:

```
   create
       Create a stash entry (which is a regular commit object) and return its object name, without storing it anywhere in the ref namespace. This is intended to be useful for scripts. It is probably not the command you want to use; see
       "push" above.
```

O comando `create` irá criar uma referência de `stash` e retornar seu id, porém, não irá colocá-lo na pilha de `stashes`. Portanto se você realizar o comando `git stash list`, ele não estará lá.

Por exemplo:

```
$ git stash create
7iFcnyu9Nxtzrmaskq2eZT5MGUK3CgfQpSRj48HV
```

Esta -> `7iFcnyu9Nxtzrmaskq2eZT5MGUK3CgfQpSRj48HV` é a referência do `stash` criado, conforme a própria documentação nos diz, isso é útil quando utilizado em scripts, onde condicionalmente (ou por qualquer outra razão) você pode guardar várias referências de `stashes` e armazená-las utilizando o comando `store` quando lhe convier:

```
$ git stash store 7iFcnyu9Nxtzrmaskq2eZT5MGUK3CgfQpSRj48HV
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: Created via "git stash store".
```

O comando `store` irá incluir a referência na pilha de `stashes`, você pode também alterar o label ao incluir na pilha:

```
$ git stash store -m "Meu stash fantastico" 7iFcnyu9Nxtzrmaskq2eZT5MGUK3CgfQpSRj48HV
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: Meu stash fantastico
```

Comment: acho q entendi, tipo um script que faz pull nos repositórios, mas antes quer fazer um stash e deixar um comentário. obrigado :)